# Triangulation of S^2xS^2

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, symplectic-topology

Could someone tell me or give a reference for the minimal triangulation of $S^2\times S^2$ and $S^2\times S^1\times S^1$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: Chapter 4 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404465v1.pdf may be of interested to you. I doubt that something is known about minimal triangulations of 4-manifolds, but you might ask the author of that preprint.

Comment: I believe the minimal triangulation of $S^2 \times S^2$ has 6 $4$-dimensional simplices.  It depends on what your "rules" for triangulations are.  I'm using unordered delta complexes.  Do you want a simplicial triangulation?  You'll need many more simplices in that case.

Comment: This other paper of Lutz is more relevant to your question: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506372.pdf. In particular, Theorem 40 says that the vertex-minimal triangulations of $S^2\times S^2$ have 11 vertices. It is not unique but Lutz conjectures that the $f$-vector $(11, 55
, 150, 170, 68)$ is component-wise minimal. (I am assuming you want a simplicial triangulation, as opposed to Ryan Budney's answer),